# Duplicate Order Issue while click multiple time place order button - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, onestepcheckout, amasty, order-duplication

I am facing the issue on the checkout page. If customer click on the place order button multiple time then multiple order will be placed with the same quote id.

I am using Amasty One step checkout extension and this issue only happens if I enable this extension.

This issue produce in the Magento cloud (My staging and integration environment) only. The same code working fine in my local and dev environment.

Please check these screenshot,
[image]
[image]

**Note**:

- Disabled class applying when I click on the place order button.
- [Magento 2 Duplicate Orders](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261247/magento-2-duplicate-orders) I have created this module also to prevent duplicate order. But it did not work.

Please help me. Your help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's nice to see you after a long time.
For the above issue, you can disable the place order button based on certain conditions as per your need and prevent duplication of orders.
You can refer to these solutions
[Magento 2 Disable/Enable Place Order Button on checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266342/magento-2-disable-enable-place-order-button-on-checkout)

And also this solution https://zanetabaran.com/how-to-in-magento-2-how-to-move-checkout-buttons-to-order-summary-only-on-desktop/amp/

Please upvote the answer if it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution: disable the place order button after the customer clicked this button.

You should fix it by updating the related JS file to set `this.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(false)` to make the place order button disabled.

In magento default, the JS file is vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/default.js, function `placeOrder`.

You can check how magento default has done it: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.5/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/default.js#L140